# Is java detecting the wrong protocol in the url?

Tags: java, cloudflare

I'm trying to setup a redirect on some of my websites from http to https.

I'm doing this programatically in java, because I have a number of websites running in the same servlet container/web app, and only some of them are hooked up to cloudflare, so only some of them can use https.

The coding *seems* quite simple:

```
String requestURLLower = req.getRequestURL().toString().toLowerCase();

if ( isCloudflareSite && requestURLLower.startsWith("http:")) {

    StringBuilder requestURL = new StringBuilder(requestURLLower);
    System.out.println("Got requrl lower " + requestURLLower + " scheme " + 
    req.getScheme() + " is secure " + req.isSecure());

    String queryString = req.getQueryString();
    if (queryString != null) {
        requestURL.append('?').append(queryString);
    }

    String link = Strings.replace(requestURL.toString(), "http:", "https:");

    System.out.println("RURLLOWEr redirecting to " + link + " from " + 
    requestURL);

    res.setStatus(301);
    res.setHeader( "Location", link);
    return;
}
```

When I run this code, the browser redirects too many times and gives an error.

The initial url I put in the browser was https itself:
https://www.xxx.com.au/xxx?page=hello

The output from the program after entering that exact url in my browser is this:

```
Got requrl lower http://www.xxx.com.au/xxx scheme http is secure false
RURLLOWEr redirecting to https://www.xxx.com.au/xxx?page=hello from 
http://www.xxx.com.au/xxx?page=hello
```

And this output was repeated about 20 times from the one page load.

Am I missing something really obvious here, or is java not detecting the protocol?

The only thing I can think of is that it is related to the https being provided by Cloudflare.

Comment: I missed the point, sorry. You put "http:", not "http".

Comment: are you talking about line 3? "https" also starts with "http" ...if I only used "http" then all requests would be redirected

Comment: now i'm a bit confused. Are you sure you are entering https://... ? Because if that's the case, your if would never be true, as "https:" doesn't start with "http:" Notice the ":"

Comment: that's exactly my point.  It should never be true, but if you look at the output from the system.outs, you can see that req.getRequestURL() is saying that the url is http:// not https://  - even though I both originally used https:// and redirected to it.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL provided by Cloudflare is between the user and Cloudflare.  Cloudflare (using the "flexible" https setting) actually connects to the server using http.